# adding gamedev to "close as offtopic" migrate

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice to have the option to migrate questions from SO to gamedev as well, if the programming question is very related to game programming.

Answer (score 13):

> ...if the programming question is very related to game programming.

then the question is *not* off-topic for Stack Overflow.

You can leave a comment suggesting that it might be better served on GameDev.  If the OP agrees, you can flag it for moderator attention and we'll migrate it.  I just don't want to force programming related questions off of Stack Overflow if that's where the author wants them.

Comment: ...I still don't see the purpose of GameDev, when SO serves it's audience perfectly well :P

Comment: @Earlz - I agree there's a lot of overlap, but GameDev includes (I assume) level design etc. which would be off topic for SO.

Comment: @Earlz Good point lets shut down http://tex.stackexchange.com/, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/, and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ too. Let just ignore that "Stack Exchange is a growing network of individual communities, each dedicated to serving experts in a specific field." and that by preventing questions relating to game development from being migerated you are completely ignoring the point of the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 6):

There's a limit of 5 migration paths. As all are currently filled you'd have to come up with a compelling reason why Game Development should replace one of them.

Comment: *current* limit. It's not a set-in-stone performance-imposed limit of 5 slots is it? Although I don't agree GameDev would make a good #6 or even #7.

Comment: @Richard - true, but Jeff did say it was unlikely to increase.

Answer (score 3):

Read this answer: https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14/11826
That's why. The OP will have the benefit of knowing a most appropriate answer.

Sure that a programmer should know how to answer some questions, but a game programmer should know **better**, as it may already have tested the answer on various real world situations, in his own games.

We on GD.SE suffer a lot from cross-posting, when the user here on SO get tired of waiting for an answer, or get the Q migrated, and then cross-post. That doesn't benefit the community.