# Voting to migrate is too restrictive

Tags: feature-request, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)
> [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

Now that there are dozens and dozens of Stack Exchange sites, the fact that the "vote to close: offtopic" options box lists only five of those sites is somewhat silly. This restriction is arbitrary, as the software could simply provide a list via drop-down, and it creates extra work for high-level moderators, who then have to respond to a "please move this appropriately" flag.

[image: Vote-to-close: offtopic suggestion box]

This has been [brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82350/adding-gamedev-to-close-as-offtopic-migrate), but the answers are somewhat contradictory.

> ...I just don't want to force programming related questions off of Stack Overflow if that's where the author wants them.

Then don't allow moderators to move questions at all!

> There's a limit of 5 migration paths. ...

That limit is an arbitrary software restriction which can be dealt with via a smarter UI, and I think it should be removed.

Comment: Do you mean voting to *migrate* is too restrictive? Because you can vote to close as off-topic without specifying where it would be on-topic.

Comment: Dangit, it's getting too dang hard to find duplicate postings. I'll just take my complaint to that question. I hope no one here accuses me of necromancy.

Comment: Yes, this one was pretty hard to find. I knew I had seen it *somewhere*, though...

Comment: Given some of the cruft that does get migrated from stackoverflow, I would prefer to make the list even more restrictive.  I think serverfault, and superuser should probably be removed from that list.    If something really needs to be moved, just flag it.

Comment: @Zoredache - or remove all, and just link the "close" and "flag" options, such that a vote of "off-topic" automatically sends a "please move this elsewhere" flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*::looks furtively at his ♦ on some other sites and begins chortling uncontrollably::*

Well, if you're a moderator you can get a rather more powerful interface
[image]

but right now this is restricted to diamond mods and team members. Presumably because we're supposed to be really-extra-super-special trustworthy.

**So how can you--a not particularly privileged user--take advantage of this spiffy power?** You can flag for a moderator's attention. I generally use a comment like *"Better on Foo.SE."*. If you are right the moderator will take care of it for you *and* you get an increment in flag weight. Yeah!

Comment: So, we can migrate to only five sites, but it takes a diamond to migrate elsewhere? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @eykanal Considering how many false positive moderators see, and how many people **think** they know where a question goes, it's honestly not such a big issue. On average, on a site like Super User, there is only about 5 to 10 flags a week out of probably 500 that require us to migrate to another site.

Comment: @Diago - so remove all migration abilities. Having just five arbitrary sites listed doesn't make sense. (Also, I re-posted the issue in the [appropriate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/110996#110996),

Comment: @eykanal: Well traditionally it has been declined because adding more than 5 would just clutter the close menu.  Also in the earlier days, I imagine off-topic questions were fairly frequent hence the need for migrating to the big 5 (instead of just closing). But it's better this way... people screw up migrations all the time.  So much crap has been wrongly sent to [programmers.se] just because it's an option. We shouldn't want that to happen to other sites as well and let moderators handle the actual migration process. We'll stick to the suggesting.

Comment: @eykanal Your argument is flawed for various reasons. There is a need to migrate questions, and with even just 5 people get it **wrong 50% of the time**. Right now, if someone asks for a unique migrations, the moderators can talk to each site moderator directly and decide if it is the correct migration. Not every question has a place, and it's 100% more important to have a question go to the right place. I have seen a question bounce between 5 different sites because the people that migrated it on 5 different sites got it wrong. The user ended up leaving. That's one of a few instances.

Comment: @Diago - I think your "50%" comment helps my point. Remove them all and just have all "offtopic" votes automatically send a moderator flag to check the question out.