# Why can't I request a question to be moved to any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, migration

The question [How can I improve my Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464544) probably ought to go on Stack Exchange site *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)*. There's even a comment (with seven upvotes) to that effect:

> We have a very nice sister site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), for this sort of thing.

The poster has only one reputation point, so I'm inclinded to assume he's new, and just doesn't know this; that said, I thought I could move the question using the "Close" functionality, since one of the options is:

> off-topic because…

And then:

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Yes, exactly! But clicking that, I'm forced to choose between meta, Super User, TeX, DBA, and SharePoint. Of course, none of these are what I want. While suggestions are nice, why can't I manually pick one? (I need other people to agree anyway for the question to successfully close.)

Am I missing something, or is this a bug/feature? (Have eight people thought this question should move, but none of us can?)

Comment: see also: [Voting to migrate is too restrictive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110994/voting-to-migrate-is-too-restrictive)

Comment: Also Related: [make-migration-paths-just-another-off-topic-reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215054/)

Comment: @Servy Yup, I'm a duplicate. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.